# Adding to JList with button

Tags: java

I'm trying to add to a JList with something minor as a sort of prototype, but I'm running into an issue when I click the Add button.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String[] nums = {"a", "b", "c"};
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Try");
    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    JList list = new JList (nums);
    int column = nums.length+1;
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(column, 2));
    pane.add(list);
    JButton addpiece = new JButton("Add");
    pane.add(addpiece);
    addpiece.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int j = nums.length;
            nums[j+1] = "input";
        }
    });
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

I get an error when I click the Add button. I want it to print out input in addition to the other members of the JList.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided I see the following issue:

You're declaring a fixed and final array called nums:

```
final String[] nums = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

And when you're clicking the button you're executing this code:

```
int j = nums.length;
nums[j+1] = "input";
```

You have two problems:

**Final** fields cannot be modified.
**Arrays** in java are a fixed size.

To handle your JList properly, you have to do this in another way:

For your reference:

http://www.seasite.niu.edu/cs580java/JList_Basics.htm